# when using a mac VM with VMWare, how do I use command key within the VM?

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have a apple computer, and am running the apple operating system within a VM on that machine.  The VM is running with VMWare.

How do I send keyboard combos that use the command key to the VM?  When I use the command key with the VM open, fullscreen or not, the keyboard combination always goes to the host instead of the VM.  So, for instance, if I hit command-Q then the entire VM closes instead of the program I have open in the VM.

(The VM does have the VM client tools installed)

Its really killing me to having to mouseclick everything in the VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had to figure this out myself.

Click the Wrench icon or choose Settings from the Virtual Machine Window. Click "Keyboard and Mouse" and choose the Mac profile.

I also had to reboot my VM afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

You just use the Windows key: [Using Mac Keyboards in a Virtual Machine](http://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.fusion.help.doc%2FGUID-AFA596FD-7F5F-472F-BA5C-D54F84A61554.html)

Comment: It is a MAC VM running on a Mac host.  What window key are you referring to?

Comment: What are you using to access the Mac VM?

Comment: I'm sorry I may not understand your question- I'm using VMWare Fusion to run the VM.  The host is a laptop, I'm typing on its keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I also think your answer lies in the keyboard & mouse settings.
I had myself a slightly different problem: I found a ready-made VM and all was working except command-clic.
The solution was also there: when you double-clic "Mac profile" in the keyboard & mouse settings, you have to disable "Button 3" to have command-clic working (at least in my case).
Hope this may help someone. :-)